# Calculating the velocity lost in a billiard's ball upon hitting a wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Imagine I have a billiard ball with mass m traveling at v meters/second and hitting one of the walls of a billiard table at angle α. The wall has e factor of elasticity.

What other parameters I need to know in or to calculate the loss in speed by the ball, and how can I calculate the actual change in speed?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you wish to account for coefficient of friction, angular velocity or air resistance?

Comment: Can do without air resistance, but friction and angular velocity ARE important for me. This problem is killing me as I have a very poor background in physics.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the unrealistic assumption that cushions do not deform then, at the moment of collision, the component of the velocity vector perpendicular to the cushion is reflected exactly if the ball has no spin (i.e. it is translating without any kind of rotation).

Things become very different when spin on the ball is involved and the cushions do not provide a perfectly elastic collision. In this case, some further assumptions are in order. For instance, it is reasonable to assume that the loss in velocity in the direction perpendicular to the cushion is proportional to the magnitude of that component of the velocity and that the coefficient is usually close to (but obviously less than) 1.

The velocity of the ball after collision also depends on the friction between the ball and the cushion, so this is another factor that needs to be known. This is where spin on the hitting ball must be taken into account when computing the resulting velocity. It must be noted though, that because of the spin, a ball might actually *gain* velocity, rather than lose.

As mentioned in the OP, the elasticity of the cushion itself is important. Experience shows (especially on American pool tables) that if a ball is hit hard against a cushion at a certain angle, the trajectory straightens up, or reverses even. This is due to the elastic component of the cushion which effectively behaves like a spring that tends to send the ball back on the line it came from.

So, to summarise, the important parameters for the problem at hand are: attenuation along the perpendicular, friction and elasticity.

Comment: "If you make the unrealistic assumption that" Even with that assumption the ball may _start_ spinning due to the collision.